# Insert all javascript files from a dir as scripts in Jade programmatically

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a Jade file `index.jade` and I have a dir `public\js` that contains a few js script files.

```
views
    index.jade
public
    js
        a.js
        b.js
        ...
```

Is there a way to automatically and programmatically include them all as scripts in the `index.jade`?

```
script(src='/js/a.js')
script(src='/js/b.js')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.  Before we get into the solution let's talk about why it's better to NOT do it.

Jade/pug compiles all of the templates into an in-memory JavaScript function so when your users request a page it's very fast as there's no disk access required.  Disk access is usually the slowest part of a web request, and it's why there are so many caching and CDN solutions out there.  When you read the file system for these files every request in to that page will be scanning the disk multiple times, first to read the directory then to insert the files to the output.

Will these script files really be changing so often that you need to incur this disk access on every request?  If you have so many script files that it's inconvenient to add them individually then you could probably group the script tags into a single template and use [inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) or [mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) to help you.

With that, said if you still really want to do it this way here's how to do it...

You need to read the files in your route and pass the array to the template:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
  // you should use a loop with a regex like ([^\/]+$) here to strip out the directory names
  // this will be specific to your server's file system setup
  res.render('<viewname>', scripts);
}
```

Then in the template:

```
each script in scripts
  script(src= script)
```